# Count the number of entries in the table

Tags: sql, count

I have a table allData

```
id     name       
1      meat
2      chicken
3      fish
4      chicken
5      fish
6      chicken
```

and table relevantData

```
id        name
1         meat
2         fish
```

I want to count the total number of occurrence per name in `allData`, but only for names which appear in `relevantData`. I.e.
The result I want to get :

```
id       name     count
1        meat     1
2        fish     2
```

I thought about the query:

```
Select count(*) from allData group by name
```

Not sure how I correlate with `relevantData`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hint: `join` the 2 tables and then use your query

Comment: As you don't actually need the data from `allData` just count the occurrences in `relevantData`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the point of view, you are interested in `relevantData`, that's the base of your query. You can use a correlated subquery, no need to use join or group-by:

```
SELECT rd.name, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM allData ad WHERE rd.name = ad.name) AS Count
FROM relevantData rd
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5689f/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM allData WHERE name in (SELECT name from relevantData) GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply join them together:

```
SELECT  a.id, a.name, COUNT(*) AS CntCol
FROM    allData a
        INNER JOIN relevantData r ON a.name = r.name
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.name, Count(1) AS TotalCount
FROM allData a
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM relevantData WHERE a.name = name)
GROUP BY a.name
```

Just group it by id and check if it contains in relevantData